# Why In the Taylor's remainder theorem they used "$\equiv$" sign?

Tags: taylor-expansion

> Assume that $f(x)$ has $n+1$ continuous derivatives on an interval
> $\alpha\le x \le\beta$, and let the point $a$ belong to the interval.
> For nth degree Taylor polynomial $P_n(x)$ let $R_n(x)\equiv
>  f(x)-P_n(x)$ denote the remainder in approximating $f(x)$ by $P_n(x)$.
> Then
>
> $$R_n(x)=\frac{(x-a)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}f^{(n+1)}(c_x), \quad  \alpha\le
>  x\le \beta$$with $c_x$ an unknown point between $a$ and $x$.

I don't know why they wrote $R_n(x)\color{red}{\equiv}f(x)-P_n(x)$.

Comment: Sometimes that symbol is used to mean "defined to be equal to."

Comment: What do you mean by $\equiv$.

Comment: I asked a similar question of sorts a while back [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3068204/what-is-the-difference-between-and-equiv). But basically it can often be used to denote definitions or identities; you can think of it as an equal sign underlined for emphasis (intuitively, of course, not literally).

Comment: @B.Goddard but here isn't the right side and left side equal ? why we defined to be equal?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer I read about their differences before but here I don't understand whether  it means it is an identity or something else.

Comment: In this case, it means we're defining the object "$R_n(x)$" to be equal to $f(x) - P_n(x)$, i.e. the error in approximating $f(x)$ by $P_n(x)$.

Comment: Oh I got it thank you.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah it is identity sign.